# Catch all routes for Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask with React. I'd like to create a catch all route similar to something like this (although this doesn't work):

```
@app.route('*')
def get():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Since my app will use React and it's using the index.html to mount my React components, I'd like for every route request to point to my index.html page in templates. Is there a way to do this (or is using a redirect the best way)?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can follow this guideline: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this will just catch all otherwise unspecified route paths, or if it will override other more specific routes? Like if right above this I had a route for `/mypath` would it still be there or would this overrule it by catching everything?

Comment: @MaxWiederholt Replace the return statement with `return render_template('index.html')`.

Comment: @theferrit32 You can still use other routes, so `/mypath` should still work. Only non-defined paths will be re-routed to the catch all.

Comment: I don't see the same route pattern in the provided url, also this route works only for /, using something else returns 404. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Doesn't work for path's like `/foo/bar.baz`.

Comment: @Displayname Nested paths like `/foo/bar.baz` work perfectly well for me using this pattern.

Comment: Doesn't work for POST requests.

Comment: It works well but if you have some settings to handle static contents it doesn't work. for example: Flask(__name__,static_url_path='',static_folder='web/static',           template_folder='web/templates') I think the problem is around the static_url_path setting.

Comment: for POST just add `@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

Comment: Updating the url from this answer to a newer version: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#url-route-registrations