# How to route all requests to a singe azure function and maintain the route

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-functions

I'm trying to run a Flask app in an Azure function to handle a small website. I can't figure out how to get the routing and proxying in Azure to work. Here's the flask app.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import mimetypes

from flask import Flask, render_template
from azf_wsgi import AzureFunctionsWsgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/got')
def got():
    return render_template('got.html')

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return AzureFunctionsWsgi(app).main(req)
```

Now what I want to do is route all incoming HTTP requests to my function app to this single function in a way that the paths match the routes in the Flask app. I've tried many different configurations of proxies.json and host.json, but non work.

Comment: Here an example to catch all routes/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777770/catch-all-routes-for-flask

Comment: That doesn’t solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looks like [`azf_wsgi`](https://github.com/vtbassmatt/azf-wsgi) is deprecated in favor of [official support in Azure Functions for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/pull/45). I believe it would be best to switch to that.

---

You basically have to make 2 changes as documented in the [azf_wsgi readme](https://github.com/vtbassmatt/azf-wsgi#configure-azure-functions-to-hand-off-to-your-wsgi-app). Here are the same for reference

1. `host.json`

```
{
    "version":  "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    }
}
```

2. `function.json`

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "app/{*route}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```