# Post request from react to flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to send a post request from react to flask using the following code:

```
function App() {

  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const clicked = 'clicked';
  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    // POST request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React Hooks POST Request Example',action: 'clicked' })
    };
    var myParams = {
      data: requestOptions
    }
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', myParams)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setAccessToken(data.access_token));

// empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like componentDidMount in classes)
}, []);




  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="leftPane">
      
      <div className="joyStick"   >
        <Joystick  size={300} baseColor="gray" stickColor="black" ></Joystick>

        </div>
        <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
        <p>The access token is {accessToken}.</p>


      
      </div>
```

And the flask code is

```
  from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

import time
from flask import Flask
import sys


robotIP="10.7.4.109"
PORT=9559
app = Flask(__name__)

access_token='a'
action="d"


@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    
    return {'time': time.time()}
    

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def nao():
    nao_json = request.get_json()



if not nao_json:
    return jsonify({'msg': 'Missing JSON'}), 400

action = nao_json.get('action')
access_token= action+'s'

print(access_token, file=sys.stderr)


return jsonify({'access_token': access_token}), 200
```

But every time I run both them both, I get the 'msg': 'Missing JSON' message I have defined and the data from react is never available in flask,even though the get request works.I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually is that this is a cross origin request which must be allowed by the server.

Place this function on your Python code:

```
@app.after_request
def set_headers(response):
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "*"
    return response
```

Note:

- If react is served from the same server this won't be necessary.
- You should set the value of these headers to be as strict as possible on production. The above example is too permissive.

---

You could serve your React aplication from Flask, thus not requiring these headers to be set. You could use something like this to serve the main react file:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<string:path>')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path: str):
    current_app.logger.debug(path)
    return bp_main.send_static_file('path/to/dist/index.html')
```

Where `path/to/dist/index.html` would be on the static folder.

See more at:

- [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=Access-Control)
- Stackoverflow: [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)
- Stackoverflow: [Catch all routes for Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777770/catch-all-routes-for-flask)